# How to show error code in C on Vscode in "Problems" section

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I want to ask how to show an C / C++ error message in problems section. What extension I should install?

[image]

Comment: Maybe use rather VS Community instead ?

Comment: Compile? Does it show up there then?